# Refreshing JavaFX imageview after overwritting displayed file?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a file called `cache.png` which is displayed in a ImageView as follows:
public class ImagePanel extends UiPart {

```
private static final String FXML = "ImagePanel.fxml";

@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

public ImagePanel() {
    super(FXML);
    imageView.setImage(new Image("/assets/cache.png"));
}
```

Now I have a method which actually replaces the existing `cache.png` file with another file **but** keeps the same name i.e. `cache.png`

```
public void importImage(Image image){
    Path from = Paths.get(image.getUrl());
    Path to = Paths.get("src/main/resources/assets/cache.png");
    try {
        Files.copy(from, to, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    //TODO
}
```

When I run my app, naturally the Imageview does not update. How can I notify the Imageview to manually repaint the node so that the new image can be displayed? I tried using two different images i.e. two different path but imageview doesn't update either way.

```
public class ImagePanel extends UiPart<Region> {

private static final String FXML = "ImagePanel.fxml";

@FXML
private ImageView imageView;

public ImagePanel() {
    super(FXML);
    imageView.setImage(new Image("/assets/cache.png"));
}

public void refresh() {
    imageView.setImage(new Image("/assets/cache2.png"));
}
```

Comment: Pls make sure that setImage is invoked in UI Thread (Try to wrap it with Platform.runLater). May I take a look at ImagePanel.fxml?

Comment: Hi, I have already fixed this - this bug was due to me calling setImage on new instance of the ImagePanel rather than the first instance already called.